# Multiple Pages Shared by One Menu

Tags: website-design

I'm planning to create a website with many webpages which are shared by a navigational menu.

For example: www.apple.com

Do I have to create separate html files with the same menu code or is there an easier way to accomplish the same task? (using javascript, php, etc)

Comment: This would be far better fit for stackoverflow as it is about coding the menu, rather than any graphical aspect of the menu.  I'm not someone that uses dreamveawer, but I'm pretty sure it has something that is called `library` that, to my understanding works like this: You can store html in this library and place it in multiple documents with some specific code that it gives you. The places where you would put these codes will be filled with the library content stored in the library ( in your final html files ). This would probably work for small websites.

Comment: On the other hand that is pretty much software equivalent for the php include: `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`. As far as javascript goes, in jquery you can use load to 'include' content from external files really easily http://api.jquery.com/load/ ( not that I'd recommend it for something as important as menu since it would be totally lost if js would be disabled ).

Comment: For everyone itching to answer, the question has been asked in stackoverflow now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160267/creating-several-webpages-sharing-a-navigational-menu

Answer (score 1):

I would truly consider using a platform such as WordPress. There are many themes that can be easily customized to fit your needs accordingly. Navigational menus can be edited very easily and moved around. There are many handy plug-ins that you can also get on Code Canyon from Theme Forest.

I hope I was helpful.